# What are standard file sizes used for web server load testing?

Tags: file, webserver, performance-testing, load-testing, nginx-ingress

I am looking for some standard file sizes that can be used on web server to load test its performance capabilities.

The files will he hosted on web server such as nginx, apache etc.
Client will request the different file sizes such as images, css java script or other code files.

So for that, I am looking for some pre defined sample files that can be used. And the standard file sizes which are applied mostly in performance testing.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are neither "standard" files nor sizes, each web site/application has its own collection of unique resources.

For example if I open this website and look at browser developer tools I can see that files sizes vary from 1 byte to 478 kilobytes.

[image]

The number of files (and their sizes) will be different for different sites so instead of focusing on finding "standard" ones I would rather recommend paying attention to the specifics of the file retrieval process, for example:

1. Real browsers download these files in parallel, mostly they use [6 parallel threads](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html) for downloading resources and making [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests
2. Real browsers do download these files but mainly they do it once, on subsequent requests the files are being returned from browser [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
3. You should rather focus on your application domain(s), if the files are external (come from 3rd-party sources) - it doesn't make a lot of sense to include them into your load testing scope

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri  i totally get your point. I was just curious to know if I use different file sizes and access them from external clients how it'll impact performance. So that's why i asked for if there's some file resource from where I can download.